# Lazy initialization in event handler

Tags: c#, event-handling, lazy-initialization

I'm wondering how to "lazy" instantiate the object from an event handler

If I have a WinForms application and two buttons for example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //MyClass obj = new MyClass();

    MyClass obj;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        obj = new MyClass();
        obj.StartWork();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        obj.StopWork();
    }
}
```

Since we won't need to access MyClass' members before the user clicks button1, it would make sense to only instantiate the class in that event handler. However, clicking on the second button will throw null reference exception, because obj variable in that scope doesn't reference anything.

Comment: shouldn't button2 be disabled until button 1 is pressed, can you not do this with only a single button?

Comment: you can wrap obj in a proprety, instantiate it in the get method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Lazy<MyClass> obj = new Lazy<MyClass>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        obj.Value.StartWork();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        obj.Value.StopWork();
    }
}
```

Accessing its `Value` property will force the creation of object.

You can also supply a custom initialization function to `Lazy` constructor.

Comment: Thank you. That works. So with the Lazy<T> class, the creation only happens when we use the value property in code, not before?

Comment: Surely that is not going to build as it is. `MyClass` will be initialized on construction. The event handler bodies will fail to compile.

Comment: @user: Right. (But I forgot to change the type to `Lazy<MyClass>` in my sample—now fixed).

Comment: @Gusdor: I fixed the type to be `Lazy<MyClass>`. Otherwise I can't see why it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

This should stop the exception:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // You need to make sure that obj is not null when this button is clicked.
    // One way is to disable this button until button1 is pressed. 
    // Or you can add this if statement.
    if(obj != null)
    {
        obj.StopWork();
    }
}
```

But your statement

> because obj variable in that scope doesn't reference anything

is wrong. `obj` can be accessed by all the methods in your `Form1` class. So when you click on `button1` first, then you instantiate your **class variable** `obj`, which can be used anywhere in your class. But you need to add the `if(obj != null)` in case the user clicks on `button2` first.

Comment: It's not global—it's a field.

Comment: It is global within your Form1 class. But you probably received the NullReferenceException by clicking on button2 without first clicking on button1.

Comment: `member`, no globals in c#

Comment: @Chris: There is no such thing as “global within”. Global is global, and there are no globals in C#.

Comment: obj is class variable.

Comment: I am talking about scope. I am not saying that obj is a global keyword, but rather that all of the methods in the Form1 class has global access to it. But I'm sorry for using the wrong word. I know what a variable is and what a property/field/class variable is.